# Regular Expression in python for several numbers separated by slashes

Tags: python, regex

I would like to be able to detect the following expressions with regex if you could help me:
For example 
it should be able to detect just a number 80
but also 80/60
and also 80/60/75
up to 4 80/60/75/50
and each time the last one could be XXX
for example 80/XXX
or 80/60/XXX
or 80/60/75/XXX

Thx for your help

Comment: You show your attempt

Comment: r"^[0-9]{1,4}(/[0-9]{1,4})*$"
It does not handle the XXX but thats why i am asking not a clue of how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex:

```
^(?:\d+/){1,3}(?:\d+|XXX)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lX81N4/1)

**Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:\d+/){1,3}`: Match a number followed by `/` 1 to 3 times
- `(?:\d+|XXX)`: follo
- `$`: End

Answer (score 0):

If the number at the beginning is determined than you can use:

```
r"$DETERMINED_NUMBER$/(\d{2}\/){0,2}\d{2,3}"
```

If the number at the beginning is not decided than there must be a whitespace otherwise you are going to detect the string which has more than 4 number. If that situation exist than you can use:

```
r" (\d{2}\/){1,3}\d{2,3}"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: [`^\d{2}(?:(?:/\d{2}){0,2}/(?:\d{2}|XXX))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/boptUJ/3)

If you need to match in text, use: `\b\d{2}(?:(?:/\d{2}){0,2}/(?:\d{2}|XXX))?\b`

Details:

- `(?:)` Non-capturing group
- `{n}` Matches exactly `n` times
- `{n,m}` Matches between `n` and `m` times
- `?` Matches between zero and one times
- `|` Or